# Is sending from gmail via pear secure?

Tags: php, security, smtp, gmail, pear

I'm using a form on my website to send an email using the PEAR mail function. The email will send via gmail as described here - http://www.phpmaniac.net/wiki/index.php/Pear_Mail

I will therefore need to include something like the:

```
<?php
$smtp_params["host"]     = "smtp.gmail.com";
$smtp_params["port"]     = "25";
$smtp_params["auth"]     = true;
$smtp_params["username"] = "user@gmail.com";
$smtp_params["password"] = "pass";
?>
```

Is it secure to put my username and password in the script like that? Obviously you wouldn't be able to see server-side script like this using 'View Source', but could you grab the source files via a web clipper or something and read the script that way? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should certainly use SSL/TLS for the connection - simply because sending passwords in plaintext over an unencrypted channel is a bad idea.

The login data inside your PHP script is safe as long as the PHP interpreter works properly and there are no security holes in your PHP scripts that allow an attacker to view the sourcecode of your PHP files.

Against the risk of misconfiguration causing PHP sourcecode to be visible an easy improvement would be storing the config file outside the document root.

Answer (score 1):

If someone accidently disbles php parsing on you apache, your file will be served as plain text, so i like to keep passwords in config files outside my docroot... Just in case.  Several times when building a new php modual for apche i forgot to copy a php.conf file into my httpd/conf.d/ direcoty and started apache without php. i

In theory, any insecure connection can be snooped.  However, in this case it would need to be intercepted between your server and gmails smtp server.  Also, even if you securly sent the email to the mail server, you have no certainty that they will connect securely to deliver it or the inteded receipient will securely check their email account.

In this case you just care about your basic auth being snooped.  Use gmails secure ssl connection

Be safe by assuming all email communication is not secure. (unless you encrypt the message)

Comment: Hi @Ray, maybe I wasn't clear enough - I realise that the content of the email should be considered insecure and I'm happy with that. The thing I'm worried about is someone being able to retrieve my gmail username and password from my PHP script! Do you know if it would be possible for someone to do that using e.g. a web clipper?

Comment: @user1684046 nope, your cod is safe mostly.  But i like to keep password and such outside my code in a config file as habit.  That way if i ever store my code at github or something i dont accidentally commit a password!

Comment: @user1684046 also, by keeping a config file outside docroot, you prevent accodental file exposure from revealing a password see my update.